# Returning index vector

Tags: java, vector

1- Hey i'm noob at programing but if you guys help i would apreciate it , i need in this method to return the max value of the vector that it will recive from main method but i also need to return to main method the index of with the max value was caught , so how can i do it?

```
  public static int maxOfaVector (int[] vector){
    int max = vector[0];
    int school;
      for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++){
        if(vetor[i] > vector[0]){
        max = vector[i];
        }
     }
      return max;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a method can return one and only one value. Fortunately that's all that's needed here since all you need to do is to have the method return the index of the max value just as it's already written to do. Once you have that, the calling code can easily get the max value from the array.

```
// in the main method
// assuming an int array called myArray
int maxIndex = maxOfaVector(myArray);
int maxValue = myArray[maxIndex];
```

Problems though:

- Your code has a typo, `if(vetor[i]` should be `if (vector[i]`
- And a logic error. In the same if boolean test, you should test `if (vector[i] > vector[max])` not `if (vector[i] > vector[0])`
- Also, you should test to make sure that the array has length > 0 first.

Comment: If you only have int values you could use the `Arrays.sort(vector)` method, which sorts all ints ascending. Therefore the `maxValue` would be afterwards at `vector[vector.length-1]`